# different ways of writing こ and ご？

Tags: hiragana, handwriting

When I write こ and ご I tend to write them with a straight line at the top instead of with a tail like how it's supposed to be written. I kind of have trouble writing it the proper way without making it look unbalanced. Is my way of writing them still somewhat correct and distinguishable from other hiragana?

[image]

Comment: I think it's fine, it's just your style. Just make sure you know the correct way and stroke order specially for kanjis.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These are at least readable and distinguishable. Actually, some Japanese fonts have こ/ご similar to yours (i.e., no hook at the top right):

[image: Sample from 源ノ角ゴシック]

Still, it's not a preferred way of handwriting こ/ご. Fonts for printing do not always reflect how you should actually handwrite characters. Your こ looks somewhat childish or comical to me. I basically recommend you practice the proper way.